# sed one-liner to remove all single newlines?

Tags: regex, sed

So for example,

```
A paragraph's newlines would be removed let's say
it contained only single
newlines.
```

Then the things I would want to skip out:

```
However.

Our previous pair of newlines wouldn't.
```

Comment: Just to clarify, would you like to remove the newlines in the first paragraph, but not remove the blank line between the last two?

Comment: @Brian yes, that was it. but unfortunately it was late and i made a typo. sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s not a *sed* solution — although you can always run any *sed* through *s2p* of course — but a very easy solution using *perl* is:

```
% perl -i.orig -ne 'print unless /^$/' file1 file2 file3
```

That has the advantage of being extensible to any whitespace on the otherwise blank lines, like spaces and tabs:

```
% perl -i.orig -ne 'print unless /^\s*$/' file1 file2 file3
```

In the event that have files with various line endings, like CR or CRLF, you could also do this, assuming you are running perl 5.10 or better:

```
% perl -0777 -i.orig -ne 's/\R+/\n/' file1 file2 file3
```

which will normalize all sequences of one or more Unicode line separators into single newlines.

If you have UTF‑8 files that might have (for example) U+00A0 NON-BREAK SPACE in them on otherwise empty lines, you can handle them by telling perl that they are UTF‑8 using the **‑CSD** command-line switch:

```
% perl -CSD -i.orig -ne 'print unless /^\s*$/' file1 file2 file3
```

## UPDATE

I’m really unclear what you mean by removing a paragraph.  I think you just mean joining up lines in a paragraph.

If so — if what you want to do is squeeze newlines from paragraphs, then you want to do this:

```
% perl -i.orig -00 -ple 's/\s*\n\s*/ /g' file1 file2 file3
```

It may not look like it works, but it does: try it.

Comment: so, the final perl command in your post converts everything into one gigantic line, as far as i can tell. am i using it wrong? what i wanted to do was simplify the formatting of paragraphs so that they don't read like 'chopped prose'... sorry about the typo in my question. that must have been confusing. i like your post by the way, and i am definitely going to have to learn some perl.

Comment: @magnetar: I have a typo.  You need *-00* with two 0s.

Comment: it works like a charm. thank you! say hi to those flatirons for me btw.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sed solution.

```
$ sed -n -e '1{${p;b};h;b};/^$/!{H;$!b};x;s/\(.\)\n/\1 /g;p' 5751270.txt
A paragraph would be removed let's say it contained only single newlines.

However.

Our previous pair of newlines wouldn't.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 8<"file"
while read -r line <&8
do
    if (( ${#line} > 0 )); then
        read -r next <&8
        if (( ${#next} > 0 ));then
            continue
        else
            echo "$line"
            echo "$next"
        fi
    fi
done
exec <&8-
```